# Is there an easy way to mass-fix links?

Tags: support, feature-request

NASA has moved stuff, again. The online version of "Stages to Saturn", "Chariots for Apollo" and probably many others have moved to http://history.nasa.gov (was: http://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History).

Since the underlying structure of the pages seems to have remained the same, it should be a "simple" find & replace to fix URLs.

Is it possible to mass-edit with a find & replace across all posts?

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169) suggests an internal tool exists.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I've linked a ton of answers to the JSC FDF page, which is now gone. Unfortunately I don't think it was just moved, so I'll have to upload the documents. But a mass-edit would still help.

Comment: I wonder if there's anybody at NASA we could convince to stop moving the cheese.

Comment: You can get in touch with the guys in Meta.SE. Here is one case where they helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382489/fix-broken-links-to-virtual-laboratories-in-probability-and-statistics

Comment: @NilayGhosh Good find - it links further to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314169) which instructs to post a request in the  appropriate meta (=here). I hope one of the mods see it and recognises the tool mentioned!

Comment: I've started fixing mine. I'll only do 5 a day max to keep from flooding the site. Jeez, NASA broke *everything*. Thank goodness for the Internet Archive!

Comment: @OrganicMarble just to add insult to injury, NASA changed links again... https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4205/ch6-2.html now redirects directly to a scanned PDF of "Chariots for Apollo"... So my fixed links broke again.

Comment: @Ludo the Internet Archive is looking better and better